# How to set Anaconda environment within .py file?

Tags: python, pandas, anaconda

I am trying to figure out how to call a specific Anaconda environment within a python script so that when the script is run it knows which environment to reference.

Most of the solutions seem to involve entering the environment specifically in cmd prompt (i.e. go to the environment path and then execute the code).

As I am deploying this to persons less familiar with Python, they will not be comfortable going to command prompt. Is there a way to define what environment to use in a .py python script? In other words, the code itself will know which environment to reference.

Comment: Is it an option to just specify the absolute path to the desired Python executable in the shebang?

Comment: @jhansen I was kind of thinking it would be something along those lines. How would I go about doing this? Specifically, to only change my path for just this program

Comment: You would add the following as the first line in your Python script:`#!/anaconda3/envs/<env_name>/bin/python` (or wherever the environment is located in your case). Also make sure the script is executable (`chmod +x script.py`).

Comment: Do I have to provide the full path to my environment? I.e. C:\\Program Files\... not sure if you were just simplifying

Comment: Yes, the full file path -- for my path I was assuming Unix, I don't know much about Windows. With cygwin you can probably use the shebang like `#!"C:\...\python.exe"`, otherwise you may be out of luck...